# set a matrix as an element of another matrix

Tags: python, matrix

is it possible to insert a matrix as an element of another matrix?
for example, I have this matrix as c :

```
| A  | b |
| -------- | -------------- |
| c11    | c12            |
| c21   | c22            |
```

now assume that I want to set this matrix as c11:

```
| g  | h |
| -------- | -------------- |
| r11    | r12            |
| r21    | r22            |
```

is it possible in python?

Comment: What type is your matrix in your python code ? a numpy.matrix is kind of deprecated, use class arrays

Comment: my original matrix is made by np.zeros(). i want to insert a matrix in its elements. excuse me if my English is not very well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c11 = np.array([[r11,r12],[r21,r22]])
c12 = np.array([[r11,r12],[r21,r22]])
c21 = np.array([[r11,r12],[r21,r22]])
c22 = np.array([[r11,r12],[r21,r22]]) 

c = np.array([[c11,c12],[c21,c22]])
```